# third party server for Instant chating

Tags: android

Is anybody have any idea about third party server of Xmpp smack implementation for instant chating.I want to create an android application just like whatsapp instant chating so I am integrating the smack lib I have about all knowlwdge for client side but do not have any idea about server.

Comment: Please use [the Software Recommendations StackExchange site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for requesting software recommendations, as that is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

you can try OpenFire server for Chat application, you have lot of plug-in's for this server.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/

And it's a OpenSource.

Hope this helps

check out these links

Smack - java xmpp libary - http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/

aSmack - android fork of smack - http://code.google.com/p/asmack/

ejabberd - xmpp server - http://www.ejabberd.im/

Martyer - java irc library - http://martyr.sourceforge.net/

Jerklib - java irc library - http://jerklib.sourceforge.net/